# Send broadcast Intent from native code fail

Tags: android-intent, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-code

I need to broadcast an intent from native c++ code. I am doing

> system("am broadcast -a com.example.intentreceiver.receiveIntent")

The output is

> Broadcasting: Intent
>   { act=com.example.intentreceiver.recieveIntent }

but the broadcast is not successful.

PS-instead of **am** command, **mkdir** or **mv** command works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally worked on other device running android 4.1.2. I was trying on android 5 lollipop and did not work.

**update**: it was a false positive. Finally after examining logs, I made the following changes in manifest and it worked.

```
android:isolatedProcess="false"
```

Comment: Any idea why this does not work on android 5? I am trying to do the same and for me even basic command like mkdir do not work. Thanks

Comment: The sender application's AndroidManifest.xml.
well I was trying to send intent from Chrome to the device so playing around with Chrome's native code.

Comment: Ah no! I am developing at framework level so no application's AndroidManifest.xml